# Function always returns False. Why?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a VBA script per mail item for `ThisOutlookSession` and ignoring the irrelevant parts of the code to my current problem, I am calling the following function:

```
Function WriteBatFile(inVar As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo err_handle:

    Dim sFile As String
    sFile = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\myScript.bat"

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFile)

    oFile.WriteLine "sleep 2"
    oFile.WriteLine "./myScript.sh " & inVar
    oFile.WriteLine "exit"
    oFile.Close

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

    'MsgBox "Setting True", vbInformation
    WriteBatFile = True

err_handle:
    'MsgBox "Setting false. Code: "
    WriteBatFile = False
    Exit Function
End Function
```

I call this function and test if it returns `True` or `False` accordingly:

```
result = WriteBatFile(match.Value)
    If result = True Then
        retval = Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"" -ssh ME@MYSERVER -m C:\Users\ME\Desktop\runThese.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    End If
```

However, when the function is called the `MsgBox` shows it is setting `True` but then the other `MsgBox` shows the function is setting `False`. Perhaps the problem is the line `WriteBatFile = True`?

Of course, the `Shell` command is never run. I would like your help showing me why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought is that the `error_handle` label is always being reached.  You need to exit the function after the successful code has been run.  Add `Exit Function` after `WriteBatFile = True`

Comment: There's no error - his code never exits the function before the error handler.

Answer (score 6):

Your `err_handle` is just a lable statement, all it does is tell the compiler that line X is called `err_handle` for `GoTo` statements. There is nothing keeping the code from just chugging right through it. The best way to fix your issue is to move the line `Exit Function` to right after you set `WriteBatFile` to True. So the fixed code will look like this:

```
'MsgBox "Setting True", vbInformation
WriteBatFile = True
Exit Function

err_handle:
    'MsgBox "Setting false. Code: "
    WriteBatFile = False
End Function
```

In `err_handle` after `WriteBatFile` is set to False, the program will exit the function natrually when it gets to the `End Function`. I hope this helps!

Comment: This is by far the best answer to this question so far, neither other one really addresses the root cause (that an error handler is a label and will always be reached unless an `Exit Function` or `Exit Sub` is placed before it.

Answer (score 0):

if there isn't an error the code will make the `WriteBatFile` equal true, then make it false.

```
 WriteBatFile = True

err_handle:
    'MsgBox "Setting false. Code: "
    WriteBatFile = False
```

it may be better to do something like

```
If err.number <> 0 then

    WriteBatFile = False

Else

   WriteBatFile = True

End If
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to avoid error 0 by properly exiting the function?